# Hold for Video like whatsapp custom camera activity

Tags: java, android

I need to create a custom camera activity like the one for whatsapp. I have created the custom camera layout but I can't implement the function of hold for video!!! Can someone help me please. Also the horizontal recyclerview that displays recent image thumbnails keeps crushing...... Any help with this??? Please help.......
`

```
package diary.dan.cameraapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CameraApi2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraApi2";
    TextureView textureView;
    ImageButton btn_capture;

    //check orientation of the camera
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
    }
    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    //save to File
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            camera = null;

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_api2);

        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);
        assert textureView != null;
        btn_capture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.capture_button2);

        btn_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhoto();
            }
        });

        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    private void takePhoto() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick reached: taking a picture");
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
                Size[] jpegSizes = null;

                if(characteristics != null){
                    jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                    .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                }

                //capture images with custom sizes...
                int width = 640;
                int height = 480;

                if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0){
                    width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                    height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
                }

                ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
                List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>();
                outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
                outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
                final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);


                // check orientation base on device
                int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

                ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                        Image image = null;
                        try{
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                            buffer.get(bytes);
                            save(bytes);
                        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            {
                                if(image!=null)
                                    image.close();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException{

                        OutputStream outputStream = null;
                        try{
                            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            outputStream.write(bytes);
                        }finally {
                            if(outputStream != null)
                                outputStream.close();
                        }

                    }
                };

                reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                        Toast.makeText(CameraApi2.this, "Saved "+ file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                };

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        try{
                            cameraCaptureSessions.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                        }catch (CameraAccessException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    }
                }, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Camera is misbehaving ......");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview(){
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Toast.makeText(CameraApi2.this, "Changed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(CameraApi2.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try{
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open the camera ......");

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

            //check real time permissions if running API 23 or higher
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView.isAvailable()){
            openCamera();
        }else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try{
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());

    }
}
```

`This is my layout.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CameraApi2">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/cameraImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/capture_button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capture_btn_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_tap2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tap2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/hold_for_video"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flash_btn2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_cam_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/capture_button2"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```